# perl hash load two maps

Tags: perl, hash, maps

I am trying to create  hash of functions. There are multiple functions, each of which will be called based on a key. There is a one to many relationship between a function and keys. The following works, but seems inefficient. (Note that I have more functions to load, but two functions makes the point.)

The following works but seems inefficient, especially when dealing with multiple function (two doesn't look so bad):

```
my %funcs = ( map {$_ => \&gt_3} qw (PH DO PWL DEPTH BARO ABSP));
%funcs = (%funcs,
   map {$_ => \&lt_one_third} qw (SPCO SALT RHUM));
```

What I wanted to do was this:

```
my %funcs = (map  {$_ => \&gt_3} qw (PH DO PWL DEPTH BARO ABSP),
   map {$_ => \&lt_one_third} qw (SPCO SALT RHUM));
```

I'm just failing to understand why the first works and the second doesn't. It appears to me that in each case there are two hashes being created on the right side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
my %funcs = (map  {$_ => \&gt_3} qw (PH DO PWL DEPTH BARO ABSP),
   map {$_ => \&lt_one_third} qw (SPCO SALT RHUM));
```

If you add parens around map's arguments, you get:

```
my %funcs = (map( {$_ => \&gt_3} qw (PH DO PWL DEPTH BARO ABSP),
   map({$_ => \&lt_one_third} qw (SPCO SALT RHUM))));
```

And if you clean that up, you get:

```
my %funcs = (
   map({ $_ => \&gt_3 }
      qw( PH DO PWL DEPTH BARO ABSP ),
      map({ $_ => \&lt_one_third }
         qw( SPCO SALT RHUM ),
      ),
   )
);
```

As you can see, you pass the following to the first map:

```
'PH', ..., 'SPCO', \&lt_one_third, 'SALT', \&lt_one_third, 'RHUM', \&lt_one_third
```

All you need to do is place the parens around map's args where you want them to be:

```
my %funcs = (
   map( { $_ => \&gt_3          } qw( PH DO PWL DEPTH BARO ABSP ) ),
   map( { $_ => \&lt_one_third  } qw( SPCO SALT RHUM ) ),
);
```

Most people don't know you can use parens around map's args, so they'll use the following:

```
my %funcs = (
   ( map { $_ => \&gt_3          } qw( PH DO PWL DEPTH BARO ABSP ) ),
   ( map { $_ => \&lt_one_third  } qw( SPCO SALT RHUM ) ),
);
```

That's also fine.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that but realized looking at your code that I had omitted the parens with the first map.

Answer (score 1):

Try with extra parens around both `map` (or at least around first one)

```
my %funcs = (
   ( map {$_ => \&gt_3} qw(PH DO PWL DEPTH BARO ABSP) ),
   ( map {$_ => \&lt_one_third} qw(SPCO SALT RHUM) ),
);
```

Comment: this made no difference. What's  happening (I should have said this the first time) is that all of the keys are loaded but the values are always the pointer to the first function.

Comment: @Dave NYC, mpapec's solution does fix that. The problem is that the second map was an argument to the first, but he used parens to change that.

Comment: @DaveNYC first group of keys refers to first sub, and second to well, second. https://eval.in/128104